# my C program is crashing

Tags: c, function, crash

this is a simple program to enter two numbers, print them out, then use the

function alter to alter x and y and print them out in main but for some reason it

doesn't print out "Enter two numbers", I'm able to enter two numbers anyway but then

it crashes after entering the 2nd number, can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
  int x, y;
  puts("Enter two numbers ");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  scanf("%d",&y);
  void alter(int*,int*);

  printf("Before alter x = %d  y = %d\n",x,y);
  alter(x,y);
  printf("After alter x = %d  y = %d\n",x,y);
}
void alter(int* x, int* y)
{
  *x = *x+*y;
  *y = *x**y;
}
```

Comment: You really really need to enable compiler warnings and take notice of them - the compiler would have warned you about your mistake with the call to `alter` which would have saved you a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `alter()` has two integer `pointers` as `parameter`.So,when you call the function you must give two addresses as arguments,otherwise a `runtime error` will occur & that's why your program crashes.You should write:

```
 alter(&x,&y);
```

instead of

```
 alter(x,y)
```

since your function's parameters are:

```
 int* x, int* y
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
puts("Enter two numbers ");
```

to

```
puts("Enter two numbers \n");
```

`\n` flushes output stream so that string is printed on console.

Change

```
alter(x,y);
```

to

```
alter(&x,&y);
```

as your function takes `int *` not `int`.

Comment: it worked, but "Enter two numbers" still appears after the two numbers are entered and not before they are entered

Answer (score 0):

when you compile your code. compiler gives warning for your problem

```
user1.c: In function ‘main’:
user1.c:13:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘alter’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
user1.c:10:8: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
user1.c:13:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘alter’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
user1.c:10:8: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

always looks in compiler warning. It will help you to overcome from such problem.

Here alter() takes pointer as argument and you are giving pass by value variable so gives crash

correct it as

```
alter(&x,&y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter(x,y);
```

should be

```
alter(&x,&y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the pointers which passes the address of variable instead of its value you must send the address of `x` and `y` to `void alter(int* x, int* y)` not the value of `x` and `y` itself. So change the function call from `alter(x,y);` (Which passes values to the called function) to `alter(&x,&y);`(which only passes the address of variables `x` and `y` to the pointers)